# HTML Agility Pack: DocumentNode.Descendants() returns null values

Tags: c#, html, windows-8, html-agility-pack, screen-scraping

I am using HTML Agility Pack to scrape websites for my Windows Store app. The version for Windows 8 store apps does not support XPath nor does it have a selectNodes function, but it does support lambda expressions to look up the values needed.

After extensively searching the web the only solution I see (over and over again) is to use DocumentNode.Descendants() to get back a list of elements to search within. However, for me, DocumentNode.Descendants() always returns back null values. This happens whether or not I pass in a parameter to the function.

I am getting back a response though. I can see the html for the page inside of the HtmlDocument object.

Code Snippet:

```
HttpContent loginContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", username),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
}

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress); //Gets the cookie

response = await httpClient.PostAsync(loginPageAddress, loginContent); //Logs in
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(new StringReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())); // Loads doc, can see html for the page in doc.text attribute now


HtmlNode pointsNode = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(o => o.Attributes["class"].Value == "availableNumber").FirstOrDefault(); // fails because Descendants returns null values
```

From debugging in my immediate window:

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
{HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.Descendants}
    name: null
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>.Current: null
    System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current: null
```

Any help solving this issue will be greatly appreciated! Thanks all.

Comment: even if you write `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().First()` you still have error?

Comment: Well, don't I feel dumb... First() does come back with results. Looks like I just didn't dig deep enough. Thanks Loclip!

Comment: No problem, if you have problem somewhere else modify the question